# sk-learn: cannot train decision tree with big dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, runtime-error, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm on my first project with Python and sk-learn.
In the project I have to do a prediction based on available data. 
For this I want to use the DesicionTreeClassifier. 
I did load and clean the data and startet generating a few trees.
During the generation, some datasets did fail to generate a tree, some others worked.
As I had a closer look, I figured out that the datasets that could train a tree had less then 30 rows with 9 columns each. It seems that the tree cannot go deeper than 4.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/decisionTree/readAnPrepareData.py", line 57, in <module>
    trainForest()
  File "/usr/local/bin/decisionTree/readAnPrepareData.py", line 39, in trainForest
    model.fit(X_train, Y)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 524, in fit
    X_argsorted=X_argsorted)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 340, in build
    recursive_partition(X, X_argsorted, y, sample_mask, 0, -1, False)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 306, in recursive_partition
    depth + 1, node_id, True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 306, in recursive_partition
    depth + 1, node_id, True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 306, in recursive_partition
    depth + 1, node_id, True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 306, in recursive_partition
    depth + 1, node_id, True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 272, in recursive_partition
    min_samples_leaf, max_features, criterion, random_state)
  File "_tree.pyx", line 533, in sklearn.tree._tree._find_best_split (sklearn/tree/_tree.c:4812)
ValueError: ndarray is not Fortran contiguous
```

I'm creating the tree this way:

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, Y)
```

What could cause this? Might this be because of an overflow? That would be very strange thought, as this are only such a little data...

Numpy is running on version :1.9.2
scikit-learn '0.16.1'

Comment: Could you also mention the sklearn's and NumPy's version you are running on?

Comment: I added the versions. Should be the current ones

Comment: @JohnGalt
Ehm I just did the upgrade to this versions. I looks like it works now... But I'll have closer look first

Comment: @JohnGalt Yep, upgrading to the current version did the trick. I thought I've  had already the current version, but you thaught me otherwise. 
I've you would be so nice and could put this into an answer, I'm happy to mark it as solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HerrDerb tested it out. This seems like a version regression error.

Upgrading to the latest scikit-learn, and optionally NumPy too should fix this.

I guess, relevant discussion can be read at [#1793](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1793), [#1678](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1678)